# bullnose vinyl corner hole repair

Tags: patching-drywall, hole-repair, corner-bead

I have a bullnose corner with roughly 3" hole. What is a good way to fill such a hole and repair? Can drywall patch be applied? Or some other method? Do I need mud or just spackling?

[image]

[image]

Comment: use spackle to fill the hole ... stuff some paper down below the hole to keep the spackle from going down ... drive a couple of screws partially into the corner wood inside the hole ... leave them sticking out inside the hole, so that the spackle anchors to them

Comment: Use just enough spackle  to fill the void and shape the curve.  That will leave you less area to try and match the texture and paint.

Comment: texture paint is a nightmare for repairs,  I see a previous repair at 5-O'clock from the current damage.